# Send a Document to Local Print in ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im creating a web-based POS system using asp.net MVC architecture.

There in the Invoice section after the invoice is complete I send the data to crystal report and the report send to the POS printer.

When I tested this locally, it worked.

But When I change the DB location to the server and host my application in the server and I log in to the system through the web the printout won't come out.

The reason is the hosted virtual machine itself searching my local printer name.

So then I again change it to convert the report into pdf and open it in the browser. So here the user needs to manually print the bill.

I want to know is there any way of doing this done? I have seen some web systems directly send the print once the finished invoice. Are there any other ways?

This is my code.

```
 private CryPrintInvoice PrintInvoice(int Id) {
   try {
     CryPrintInvoice invoiceReceipt = new CryPrintInvoice();
     List < ReportInvoiceMain > invoice = new List < ReportInvoiceMain > ();

     invoice = (from i in db.Invoice join c in db.Company on i.CompanyID equals c.ID where i.ID == Id select new ReportInvoiceMain {
       CompanyAddress = c.CompanyAddress,
         CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
         CompanyPhoneNumber = c.CompanyMainPhoneNumber,
         ImagePath = c.CompanyLogo,
         Invoice_Number = i.Invoice_Number,
         Payment_Type = i.Payment_Type,
         Discounted_Amount = i.Discounted_Amount,
         Invoice_Total_Amount = i.Invoice_Total_Amount,
         Invoice_Sub_Amount = i.Invoice_Sub_Amount,
         CreatedDate = i.CreatedDate,
         CustomerName = i.CustomerModel.Customer_Name,
     }).ToList();
     List < ReportInvoiceItems > invoiceItems = new List < ReportInvoiceItems > ();

     invoiceItems = (from t in db.InvoiceItems where t.Invoice_ID == Id select new ReportInvoiceItems {
       ItemName = t.Items.ItemName_Number,
         Qty = t.Qty,
         Unit_Price = t.Unit_Price,
         Line_Discount = t.Line_Discount,
         Line_Total = t.Line_Total,
     }).ToList();

     invoiceReceipt.SetDataSource(invoice);
     invoiceReceipt.Subreports["InvoicedItems"].SetDataSource(invoiceItems);
     Response.Buffer = false;
     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.ClearHeaders();

     System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
     CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintLayoutSettings PrintLayout = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintLayoutSettings();
     System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
     printerSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
     System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(printerSettings);
     invoiceReceipt.PrintOptions.DissociatePageSizeAndPrinterPaperSize = true;
     invoiceReceipt.PrintOptions.PrinterDuplex = PrinterDuplex.Simplex;
     System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pageSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(printerSettings);
     //invoiceReceipt.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pSettings, false, PrintLayout);

     return invoiceReceipt;

   } catch (Exception ex) {

     throw ex;
   }
 }
```

Comment: _"I have seen some web systems directly send the print once the finished invoice."_ -  that is only possible inside a controlled LAN environment, where the webserver can send a print-job directly to the user's nearest office printer. While _Internet Print Protocol_ is a thing, despite the name, it doesn't work over the Internet unless you configure your NAT, firewall rules, etc. The next alternative is to generate a PDF server-side and let the end-user print it themselves - or serve a HTML document that calls `window.print()` on-load.

Comment: The code you've posted has numerous resource-leak issues that you should address, and a few other code-smells too (e.g. **never** do `catch` with `throw ex` as that loses the stack-trace.